# Deserlize xml to expandobject to Dynamic child Element

Tags: c#, xml, api

My requirement is call Api and get the response from Api and save to db.The response are xml format.but same Api call i was get **2 types of xml** like this

> **Approved Response from APi**

```
<Message>
<Body>
<PaResponse>
<Approved>
</Approved>
</Paresponse>
</Body>
</Message>
```

> **Decliened Response From Api**

```
<Message>
<Body>
<PaResponse>
<Decliened>
</Decliened>
</Paresponse>
</Body>
</Message>
```

> **My Model class are**

```
class Message{

  public Body Body {get;set;}

}
class Body{
 public Paresponse PaResponse { get;set;}
}

class PaResponse{

//here is the proplem i need choose dynamically for this child object
public Approved {get;set;}

//public Decliened {get;set;}


}
```

but how can identify the child elements to deserlize dynamically

> right now  iam use this extension method to deserlize approved request.

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(this string xml)
                    where T : new()
 {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
                    {
                        return new T();
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
                        {
                            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return new T();
                    }


  }
```

**Note: Api Only provide Xml Format There is no json**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going right with your solution; You do not need to choose, instead your class `PaResponse` should have two fields for both `Approved` and `Declined`. And when your xml deserialized one of these fields will have a value different than null and the other will have a null value. You can check them to know which response you have.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Message>
  <Body>
    <PaResponse>
      <Approved>
      </Approved>
      <Decliened>
      </Decliened>
    </PaResponse>
    </Body>
</Message>
```

Copy that XML and from Visual Studio Menu choose **Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes**

Visual Studio then will create your models for you. In your case they are simple models and you already have figured them before.

Then simple C# code to deserialized

```
// I just saved the xml to a file, in your case 
// you will read it from the API
string path = @"G:\Projects\StackOverFlow\WpfApp1\Message.xml";
FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(path);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
Message message = (Message)ser.Deserialize(reader);
```